# Kotlin: How to inherit property in data class

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, data-class

I have abstract Token class declared like this:

```
abstract class Token(var index: Int = 0) {
open fun merge(toMerge: Token): Token? {
    return null
    }
}
```

I want to inherit index property in data class, like this:

```
data class CloseLoop(index: Int, var openLoopIndex: Int = 0) : Token(index)
```

But it gives me error `Data class primary constructor must have only property (val / var) parameters`

What i have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are at least two workarounds:

- Make the property `open` and [override](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-properties) it in the data class primary constructor declaration:

  ```
  abstract class Token(open var index: Int = 0)

  data class CloseLoop(
      override var index: Int, 
      var openLoopIndex: Int = 0
  ) : Token(index)
  ```
- Declare a property with another name and initialize the base class with it:

  ```
  data class CloseLoop(val theIndex: Int, var openLoopIndex: Int = 0) : Token(theIndex)
  ```

  <sup>Make it `private` if you find it appropriate.</sup>